# What is happening when I put my search condition inside COUNT() rather than in a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to return the number of players with weight 300+ lbs in these regions. I know that putting the condition inside the COUNT() instead of in a WHERE clause isn't working, but I'm not quite sure why.

I already know that the solution is to just make this COUNT(1), and follow up the FROM with a `WHERE weight >= 300`. I'm just not sure why what I've written doesn't return the same results.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN state IN ('CA','OR','WA') THEN 'West Coast'
            WHEN state = 'TX' THEN 'Texas'
            ELSE 'Other' END AS regional,
            COUNT(weight >= 300) AS heavyweights
  FROM benn.college_football_players
 GROUP BY 1;
```

The actual results should be 1590 for Other, 208 for Texas, and 186 for West Coast. Instead, I'm getting nearly 20 times those numbers as the COUNT results.

Comment: If this is MySQL you can simply change `COUNT` to `SUM`

Comment: Sure thing, how do I do that? Sorry, completely new to Stack Overflow

Comment: Count is just counting the number of records, for what you are doing you probably want something like `SUM(IF(weight >= 300, 1, 0))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
COUNT(weight >= 300)
```

is the same as

```
COUNT(*)
...
WHERE weight is not null
```

Instead, use this:

```
SUM(case when weight >= 300 then 1 else 0 end)
```

However, for MySQL, whose `true` equates to `1` and `false` to `0`, you can use:

```
SUM(weight >= 300)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is not MySQL apparently, but the first suggestion for case inside SUM worked!

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you are using MySQL, because this syntax is allowed there.

The expression `(weight >= 300)` is a boolean expression that evaluates to `0` (for false) or `1` (for true) . . . or conceivably `NULL` if `weight` is `NULL`.

The expression `COUNT(weight >= 300)` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  Well, both "true" and "false" are not `NULL`, so all are counted.

To count the value, use `SUM()`:

```
SUM(weight >= 300)
```

Comment: I'm actually not completely sure, this is from the Mode SQL tutorial.
When I enter in SUM(weight >= 300) it returns an error saying:
function sum(boolean) does not exist